# Rust Borrow Checker Question: Don't know where immutable borrow happens that prevents compiling

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to remove random elements from a Rust HashSet, but my implementation seems to use a mutable borrow and immutable borrow at the same time. I don't understand where this is happening, or how to fix it.

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use rand::seq::IteratorRandom;
fn main() {
    let mut set: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::new();
    set.insert(2); set.insert(3);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let num = set.iter().choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
    set.remove(num);
}
```

Here is a simple program that randomly chooses an element from a HashSet and then removes it. But I'm getting the following compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `set` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
8 |     let num = set.iter().choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
  |               ---------- immutable borrow occurs here
9 |     set.remove(num);
  |     ^^^^------^^^^^
  |     |   |
  |     |   immutable borrow later used by call
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
```

I don't see how a borrow occurs in `set.iter()` or `set.remove()`.

Comment: Both of these do borrow, as in `iter(&self)` and `remove<Q>(&mut self, value: &Q)`.

Comment: I see. What is the correct way to do this then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trap here is that `iter()` returns references to elements, and as such, `num` itself is a reference. More specifically, this is what it looks like to Rust:

```
let num : &i32 = set.iter().choose(&mut rng).unwrap();
```

Where now you have a reference `num` that's lingering and in conflict with the mutable reference you later want.

The fix is to get rid of the reference before calling `remove()`:

```
let num : i32 = *set.iter().choose(&mut rng).unwrap(); // Reference removed
set.remove(&num); // Convert back to reference, but to local variable
```

That resolves the conflict.

If the goal is to remove some random element, you could also remove a random index with [`retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.retain) and a function, which means there's no reference to a specific element needed.